# Insert image instead of bullets in unordered list

Tags: css

I have the following code:

```
     <div class="extra-details">
                               <ul class="browse-product-usp">

                               <li>
                                <span class="text">
                                    Dimension: 11x11 inch
                                </span>
                              </li>

                            <li>
                                <span class="text">
                                    Paper Depth: 285 gsm
                                </span>
                            </li>

                    </ul>
            </div>
```

This look in the browser as below:

[image]

My CSS is as below:

```
    .text {
              color:#333;
              font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

  }
```

when I put following code:

```
    ul{list-style-image:url(../img/arrow.png);}
```

It distorts my text from the iimage line.Please help
[image]

I want the arrows and the text in the same line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this;

```
ul {
    list-style-image:url('image.gif');
}
```

Comment: @arunes..It distorts my text from the line..please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background: url("image.gif") no-repeat scroll 0px 5px transparent;` instead of list-style-image

Answer (score -1):

**Used** to `background-image` in your `li` tag

```
ul li {
background:url("http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/silk2/resultset_next.png") no-repeat 0 3px;
line-height:25px;   
padding-left:25px;
}
```

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/YkFiKQur)***

Comment: :..I havn't downvoted you...my reputation is not that high...but I tried your code and it simply doesn't work.

Comment: @BhushanFirake ok i will give you live demo with this code just wait

Comment: This will give the whole li a background ! And not the list style. What you need to is use list-style-image:url to give the result the asker is expecting. Ps: i am not the one who down voted u ! I am just giving you a possible reason.

Comment: But now you can not use a different background for the List item. You can use double background but it is not supported by IE. The best solution was to use list-style-image:url()

Comment: great this is the answer @Rohit because with background-position we can't get the desired result so its fine :-) i hope OP will like this now........